# Request Axios post vuejs : empty data

Tags: vue.js, axios, http-post

I have a problem with an axios post request, I always do the following to send the data and it still works but today it does not work. Axios sends the empty data, however in the console log I have the data. When I test with postman everything works so I think the problem is at the query level. After several searches, I saw that the method I am using is good, but then why it does not work.If I send only one data it works. thank you for help

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form class="form-CreateOption" method="post" v-on:submit.prevent="Submit">
            <div>
                <p>Nom de l'option* </p>
                <input type="text" name="nameOption" v-model="nameOption" id="nameOption">
            </div> 
            <div>
                <p>Description*</p>
                <textarea class="detailOption" name="descriptionOption" id="" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="descriptionOption"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Prix*</p>
                <input type="text" name="priceOption" v-model="priceOption">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Image*</p>
                <input name="imageUrlOption" type="file" @change="uploadOneFileOption($event)">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Create</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name:'CreateOption',
    data(){
        return{           
            nameOption:"",
            descriptionOption: "",
            priceOption: "",
            imageUrlOption:""
        }
    },
    methods:{
        uploadOneFileOption(event){
            console.log(event)
            this.imageUrlOption = event.target.files[0];
        },
        Submit(){
            let token= localStorage.getItem('token')
            const header = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            }
            const formDatas = new FormData();
            console.log(formDatas.append)
            formDatas.append('nameOption', this.nameOption)
            formDatas.append('descriptionOption', this.descriptionOption)
            console.log(this.descriptionOption)
            formDatas.append('priceOption', this.priceOption)
            console.log(this.nameOption)
            formDatas.append('imageUrlOption', this.imageUrlOption) 
       
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/option/create-option',formDatas,header)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log({err: err})
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC2vW.jpg)

[nameOption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDS7i.jpg)

[FormData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEZxf.jpg)

[postman with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP328.jpg)

[postman without image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBtiZ.jpg)

[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D7C8.jpg)

Comment: you are using `'Content-type': 'application/json'` but you are sending formData. Can you try to change your content-type to `'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: I changed with multipart / form-data, it doesn't work.

Comment: like this it works, but my image is undefined                                                                   
 `  const fd = {nameOption : this.nameOption, imageUrlOption : this.imageUrlOption }
            axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/option/create-option`,fd,header)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log({err: err})
            });

Comment: The above works because you are sending JSON but the image is not a JSON, so it is undefined. Can you show me how you test it on Postman? You use application/json as well on Postman?

Comment: very good thanks for the explanation. I took two screenshots, one without the photo: name : postman with image, and the other with the photo: name : postman without image. The images can be found in the post above.

Comment: i see that the keys in `postman with image` are not the same as `postman without image`. The nameOption should be name_Option and same as other. you should use name_Option, description_Option, price_Option. I don't know your imageUrlOption should be image_url_Option or imageUrl_Option

Comment: should be like this: https://i.imgur.com/bU444A5.png. Try to get it work in postman first.

Comment: Yes indeed for the image part I made the modifications. But the problem remains the same. I admit that there I do not know how to do since yesterday afternoon I tried several solutions but none worked.

Comment: how do you handle image upload on backend? Are you able to upload image to backend via this API before? If the image upload never upload successfully before, I think the problem should be more related to backend.

Comment: I put a screenshot named backend in the post.

Comment: How do handle image upload ? Are you using multer so anything else? If no, I think you should check out https://github.com/expressjs/multer. If yes. can you try to rename all the keys in `postman with image` with underscore `name_Option, description_Option, price_Option, imageUrl_Option` and test it again in Postman

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, the answer to the problem lies well at the level of multer. I just moved my post route to place it first and put multer back, because I had removed it during my many tests. Thanks everything works

Comment: Cool. nice to see you are able to figure it out and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you are sending data in which one field is missing or empty which is required

Comment: precisely the field is filled. I received the data entered in the field with the console log. That's why I don't understand where the problem can come from.If, for example, in the query parameter I only enter nameOption, it works. It's when I use formDatas that it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot of the data that you are sending.
console.log(formDatas)

Comment: I added the new screenshot in the post under the name of: nameOption because I don't know how to add a photo in the comment.

Comment: console formDatas how it look like before sending

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean console.log(formDatas) wanna see the structure

Comment: fine, i put the image in the post under the name formData